# PDF/A to normal PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I submitted a paper to a conference and now they are asking me to change my pdf from PDF/A to normal PDF because editing functions are disable. Looking in the Internet, I found the following post

[How to convert PDF/A to normal PDF?](https://superuser.com/questions/441404/how-to-convert-pdf-a-to-normal-pdf)

I use Ubuntu with Document Viewer to open PDF doculents. I installed Acrobat Reader 9 to see if I find something to convert the PDF, but I had not success. Also, my PDFs are generated by pdflatex.

By reading the aforementioned post I understood that I have to have Adobe Acrobat to do the conversion, so have the following question: can I covert the PDF in Ubuntu, it is up to the person reading the document or what should I do?

Comment: It seems strange that if they have the ability to edit the PDF then they have the ability to do this on their own.  You cannot do this with Adobe Reader you actually need Adobe Acrobat which to my knowlege isn't supported on Linux.

Comment: If you have the original source document you should be able to simply recreate a normal PDF document.

Answer (score 2):

Note that PDF/A is a subset of the PDF format, and as such all PDF/A files are normal PDFs. They just don't use some features of the full PDF format. You don't need to do anything to convert a PDF/A to a PDF. It already is one.

The problem might actually be that editing has been disabled in the PDF security settings and you will need to change them from deny to allow.